# Simple newsletter form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So i have a static_pages#home in which i want people to put their email address in a form, which will save it to the database in my NewslettersController. But i it doesnt work for me, i can type in my email address and press submit but it wont be saved to the database or validated in the model.

View static_pages#home which is root

```
<%= form_for Newsletter.new, :url => { :controller => "newsletters", :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :style => "width:50%;", :placeholder => "Your email address", :class => "form-control input-sm" %>
  <%= f.submit "Keep me updated", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
<% end %>
```

Model

```
class Newsletter < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email

  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
end
```

Controller

```
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @newsletter = Newsletter.new(params[:newsletter])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @newsletter.save
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You will hear from us shortly, Thank You' }
      else
        format.json { render json: @newsletter.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

end

  resources :newsletters, :only => :create
```

EDIT:

View

```
<%= form_for @newsletter do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, :style => "width:50%;", :placeholder => "Your email address", :class => "form-control input-sm" %>
  <%= f.submit "Keep me updated", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-sm" %>
    <% if @newsletter.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@newsletter.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this email address from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% @newsletter.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor your code like this:

**app/controllers/static_pages.rb**

```
def home
  @newsletter = Newsletter.new
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= form_for @newsletter do |f| %>
```

Regarding your issue, you might want to check `@newsletter.errors` to see if the validation process succeed or not.

Try:

```
class NewslettersController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html

  def create
    @newsletter = Newsletter.new(params[:newsletter])
    @newsletter.save

    respond_with @newsletter
  end
end
```

Comment: I edited the view and controller in static pages but it still doesnt save to the database or give me any error messages. See the edit in original post. :/

Comment: The thing is you are responding in JSON if any errors occurred. Edited my answer.

Comment: <%= @newsletter.errors.messages %> which gives me this empty string {:email=>[]}. I also changed my controller to your example but nothing is being created and i dont get any error messages.

Comment: Ok, try doing `@newletter.save!`. Will raise an exception if save fail.

Comment: I tried and it didnt work, i dont think it calls the newsletters model at all. This is what i get in my terminal Started GET "/?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=4LmOn1aAOr%2BOt%2Bb8Ggc2CqheEnyb7KY8Ba3QJlFx0Gs%3D&newsletter%5Bemail%5D=weewfrehstjhsf&commit=Keep+me+updated" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-03 12:24:53 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4LmOn1aAOr+Ot+b8Ggc2CqheEnyb7KY8Ba3QJlFx0Gs=", "newsletter"=>{"email"=>"weewfrehstjhsf"}, "commit"=>"Keep me updated"}
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/applicatio